# what were the various locations associated with the names of the 24 divisions in Palestine after they returned from Persia?

Tags: kohen-priest, geography

I read that the prophets Haggai, Zechariah and Malachi divided the four families that returned from exile in the first and second waves into 24 watches at the rebuilding of the Second Temple.  Nechemiah came in the third wave of exiles from Persia and finished building the walls around Jerusalem.

In chapters 10 and 12 he listed three (in some places) different names for the watches.  "The reason there are different names in the Second Temple period is because only four Kohen families - Yeda'ayah, Charim, Pashchur, Imer - returned during Shivat Tzion, so as punishment to the other families, the mishmarot were built out of these four families. (Arachin 12b)"

**Is there a list of locations that can be attached to the 24 watches that were established when the Second Temple was first dedicated?**  I understand that even though the returned Jews had almost a free hand in conducting themselves in the Palestine area, they were still governed by Persia.  If the locations of each of the assigned watches were similar to the locations in the original First Temple design does anyone have a listing of those locations?

After the civil war and the establishment of Samaria as the new capital for the Ten Tribes were the locations adjusted to the new, much smaller jurisdiction of Jerusalem?   The new kings governing from Samaria tried very hard to divert the attention of their subjects away from the Jerusalem Temple.  That had to affect the 24 divisions’ locations.

I am not interested in the 24 divisions’ locations in Galilee, after the Romans destroyed Herod’s Temple.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501)  Richard and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: You appear to be asking here two questions, which I recommend separating into two separate posts. The first is whether the 24 priestly divisions had specific localities during the 2nd Temple era or if this was purely a post 2nd-Temple phenomenon. The second is whether the divisions of the 1st Temple had specific localities and did these change when the Kingdom split.